# Problems with string and arrays in Windows 8

Tags: c#

I have the code:

```
            StorageFile sf = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("1.png");
            IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(sf);
            byte[] fileData = buffer.ToArray();
            Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
            string text = encoding.GetString(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
            string content = @"file1=" + text + "";

            txt.Text = content;

            Item_Text.Text = txt.Text;
```

And when i'm trying to display in textbox, it doesn't display full text, but in textblock string is full. There is the image:

[image: My App]

Comment: What's your Xaml for the Textbox?

Comment: <TextBox x:Name="Item_Text" Width="400" Height="100" Grid.Row="1"/>

Comment: Textboxes are single line by default: Take a look at [How to: Create a Multiline TextBox Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742157.aspx).

Comment: But when i'm trying to put it in string and to POST it - Error is the same

Comment: Sounds like string terminators \0 in your file.

Comment: What i'm suppost to do

Comment: You can replace the \0 with a space or something. I'm not sure I understand why your opening a binary and displaying it as text.

Answer (score 0):

Line breaks is probably your problem. You can't just POST data with random line breaks.

You can try to use base64 encoding to safely transfer your binary data as text.

```
string text = Convert.ToBase64String(fileData, 0, fileData.Length, 
                                Base64FormattingOptions.None);
```